# Extract data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

Below you can see the structure of my list titled monthly_data.

[image]

This list contains data from separate tables: Export_A1.xlsx, Export_A2.xlsx, and Export_A3.xlsx.In each list there are monthly data from m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11 and m12. Below you can find sample extracted with dput.

```
list(Export_A1.xlsx = list(m1 = structure(list(English = c("English", 
"1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"7"), ...4 = c("Females", "4"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "8"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"5"), ...7 = c("Females", "10"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m2 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "10"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "0"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "9"), `14-17` = c("Males", "5"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m3 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"10"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "2"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"8"), ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m4 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "1"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "7"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "1"), `14-17` = c("Males", "5"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "7"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m5 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"4"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "9"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "8"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m6 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "5"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "1"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "6"), `14-17` = c("Males", "0"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "5"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m7 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"4"), ...4 = c("Females", "9"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "7"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "3"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m8 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "6"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "9"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "7"), `14-17` = c("Males", "9"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "1"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m9 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"2"), ...4 = c("Females", "6"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"2"), ...7 = c("Females", "9"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m10 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "0"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "8"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", "8"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "5"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m11 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "9"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m12 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "3"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "0"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "1"), `14-17` = c("Males", "4"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), Export_A2.xlsx = list(m1 = structure(list(English = c("English", 
"1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"7"), ...4 = c("Females", "4"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "8"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"5"), ...7 = c("Females", "10"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m2 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "10"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "0"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "9"), `14-17` = c("Males", "5"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m3 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"10"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "2"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"8"), ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m4 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "1"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "7"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "1"), `14-17` = c("Males", "5"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "7"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m5 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"4"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "9"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "8"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m6 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "5"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "1"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "6"), `14-17` = c("Males", "0"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "5"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m7 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"4"), ...4 = c("Females", "9"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "7"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "3"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m8 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "6"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "9"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "7"), `14-17` = c("Males", "9"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "1"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m9 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"2"), ...4 = c("Females", "6"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"2"), ...7 = c("Females", "9"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m10 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "0"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "8"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", "8"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "5"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m11 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "9"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m12 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "3"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "0"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "1"), `14-17` = c("Males", "4"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), Export_A3.xlsx = list(m1 = structure(list(English = c("English", 
"1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"7"), ...4 = c("Females", "4"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "8"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"5"), ...7 = c("Females", "10"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m2 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "10"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "0"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "9"), `14-17` = c("Males", "5"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m3 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"10"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "2"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"8"), ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m4 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "1"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "7"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "1"), `14-17` = c("Males", "5"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "7"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m5 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"4"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "9"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "8"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m6 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "5"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "1"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "6"), `14-17` = c("Males", "0"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "5"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m7 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"4"), ...4 = c("Females", "9"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "7"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "3"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m8 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "6"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "9"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "7"), `14-17` = c("Males", "9"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "1"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m9 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"2"), ...4 = c("Females", "6"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"2"), ...7 = c("Females", "9"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m10 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "0"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "8"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", "8"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "5"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), m11 = structure(list(English = c("English", "1"
), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...4 = c("Females", "2"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "4"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
"1"), ...7 = c("Females", "9"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
"0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
"0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), m12 = structure(list(
    English = c("English", "1"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
    "Belgium"), `0-13` = c("Males", "3"), ...4 = c("Females", 
    "0"), ...5 = c("Unknown", "1"), `14-17` = c("Males", "4"), 
    ...7 = c("Females", "4"), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0"
    ), `35-64` = c("Males", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0"), 
    ...14 = c("Unknown", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", "0"
    ), ...16 = c("Females", "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0"), 
    Unknown = c("Males", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))))
```

Now I want to apply `bind rows` function on this list. So after applying these functions each column needs to begin with the title of the list or in this case Export_A1.xlsx while the second column needs to have data about months or in this case m1.... etc.

I tried with this line of code but the results are not good.

```
bind_rows(monthly_data)
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is a nested list, we may need to loop over the outer list and then apply `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- map(monthly_data, bind_rows)
```

---

If the intention is to create two columns based on the inner list names and outer list names and then have a single dataset, use `.id`

```
out <- map_dfr(monthly_data, ~ bind_rows(.x,  .id = 'month'), 
    .id = 'sheet_name')
```

-output

```
> head(out, 2)
# A tibble: 2 × 22
  sheet_name     month English Citizenship `0-13` ...5    ...6    `14-17` ...8    ...9    `18-34` ...11  ...12 `35-64` ...14 ...15
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1 Export_A1.xlsx m1    English Citizenship Males  Females Unknown Males   Females Unknown Males   Femal… Unkn… Males   Fema… Unkn…
2 Export_A1.xlsx m1    1       Belgium     7      4       8       5       10      0       0       0      0     0       0     0    
# … with 6 more variables: `65 and over` <chr>, ...17 <chr>, ...18 <chr>, Unknown <chr>, ...20 <chr>, ...21 <chr>
```